# How Do I make my ship stay on the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3

What code should I put in here to make my ship stay in the stage?
My ship keeps going off the stage when I press the keys and it goes too far. How do I get it to bump into walls and make it stay on the stage?

```
package{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class Ship extends MovieClip{

        var velocity:Number;
        var shootLimiter:Number;
        var health:Number;
        var maxHealth:Number; 

            function Ship(){

            velocity = 10;
            shootLimiter = 0;
            health = 100;
            maxHealth = 100;
            addEventListener("enterFrame", move);

        }

        function kill(){

            var explosion = new Explosion();
            stage.addChild(explosion);
            explosion.x = this.x;
            explosion.y = this.y;

            removeEventListener("enterFrame", move);
            this.visible = false;

            Game.gameOver();

        }

        function takeDamage(d){

            health -= d;

            if(health<=0){
                health = 0;
                kill();
            }

            Game.healthMeter.bar.scaleX = health/maxHealth;

        }



        function move(e:Event){

            shootLimiter += 1;

            if(Key.isDown(Keyboard.D)){
                this.x = this.x + velocity;
            }
            if(Key.isDown(Keyboard.A)){
                this.x = this.x - velocity;
            }
            if(Key.isDown(Keyboard.W)){
                this.y = this.y - velocity;
            }
            if(Key.isDown(Keyboard.S)){
                this.y = this.y + velocity;
            }
            if(Key.isDown(Keyboard.SPACE) && shootLimiter > 8){
                shootLimiter = 0;
                var b = new Bullet();
                stage.addChild(b);
                b.x = this.x + 40;
                b.y = this.y + -25;
            }

            if(shield.visible == true){
                shield.alpha -= 0.0005;
                if(shield.alpha == 0){
                    shield.visible = false;
                    shield.alpha = 1;
                }
            }               
        }               
    }       
}
```

Comment: You mean you need something like this condition: `if(this.x < Stage.stageWidth - this.width)  this.x = this.x + velocity;`

Comment: @Cherniv where would I put that code in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is hard to fix as it is, but I'll give you an answer in pseudo, so you could think on how to implement it to fit in your project. Your ship is going out of the frame because it has no notion of where to stop. Lets say the ship x and y coordinates are taken from the upper left corner of the sprite, as it is in actionscript, then, every time your ship moves to the left, you must consider the following:

```
if(Key.isDown(Keyboard.A)){
    var futureX:Number = this.x - velocity;
    if (futureX <= 0){ //your ship has reached the left border of the screen
        this.x = 0;
    } else {
        this.x = futureX;
    }
}
```

things get a little more complicated when you're checking for the right or bottom border of the screen, as you need to consider the size of your stage and the size of your sprite in the calculations:

```
if(Key.isDown(Keyboard.S)){
    var futureY:Number = this.y + velocity;
    if (futureY + this.height >= Stage.stageHeight){
        this.y = Stage.stageHeight - this.height;
    } else {
        this.y = futureY;
    }
}
```

The solution for the top and right borders are trivial after this.